# Minimize sum of $k$ distinct $n$-th roots of unity.

Tags: roots-of-unity

Let $0<k<n$ be positive integers. I want to find a subset of $k$ distinct elements of the set of $n$-th roots of unity which is "uniformly spread over the unit circle".

I do not have a precise definition for "uniformly spread over the unit circle", so I provisionally change the problem to minimizing the module of the sum:

**Problem** *Let $\zeta_n=e^{2i\pi n}$ and $0<k<n$. Find distinct $0\leq i_1<\ldots<i_k<n$ that minimize:*
$$
\left\vert{\sum_{j=1}^k\zeta_p^{i_k}}\right\vert.
$$

**Question** What is the solution to the problem above? Is there always a solution of the form:
$$
\{i_j\}_{j=1,\ldots,k}=\{hj\bmod n\}_{j=1,\ldots,k}
$$
for some integer $h$? (up to the order of the $i_j$'s)

**Extra question** What are some better definitions of "uniformly spread"? With my definition, if both $k$ and $n$ are even then any subset symmetric with respect to the origin has sum equal to zero, even if it is not necessarily "uniformly spread".

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46068/how-small-can-a-sum-of-a-few-roots-of-unity-be

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It leaves very little hope to get an answer to my question.